# Node.js + Express POST request returns undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, post, body-parser

I have Node.js + express on the backend and trying to parse the body of the simple POST-request.
But getting "undefined" on the server console as the result.

I tried a lot of options I've found here on StackOverflow - nothing works.
(Seems like body-parser isn't required in the version. But doesn't work *even if included*).

Below are my code examples:

**Node.js config(Express version: express@4.17.1):**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const path = require('path');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

let ejs = require('ejs');

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.text());

/* ... Some code ... */
```

**Node.js routing:**

```
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .post('/gaapi-post', function(req, res){
    console.log('***** Post fields: ******');
    console.log(req.body);
  })
```

**Examples of POST-requests:**

```
// jQuery JSON
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/gaapi-post',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: { "x": "5", "y": "6" }, // Valid JSOP should have " instead of '
});

// jQuery simple text
$.post( "/gaapi-post", 'test');


// Curl in console
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' http://localhost:5000/gaapi-post
```

What might be changed or improved in the codes above?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

By default, req.body is undefined, and, is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as body-parser and multer. So you need to use one of this middleware. Express (4.x) has unbundled the body-parser middleware from the core framework. So, if you need body-parser, you need to install it separately:

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Here is the code sample for body-parser:

```
const app = require('express')();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```